# Best way to track IP Address and traffic source on Wordpress install

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ip

Im sure this question has been asked before and I am sure there is some way to accomplish this.

Here is my problem:  Running Google Adwords sometimes it feels like our budget gets exhausted fairly quickly and I am almost certain that it is due to competitors clicking links or having someone click the ad's.  I know Google has tried to prevent this but I just dont see that working based on a friends Adsense and it showed his ad's were being clicked on numerous times by the same IP and they were only stayin on his site for less than 10 seconds.

So no I am paranoid of spending money on PPC because of this behavior.  My question is is there anything available either on Wordpress or some script I can implement that will tell me the visitors IP address, source of traffic and how long they spent on site?

I have researched some of the free services online but either they dont offer these 3 features or they fail to work consistently.

Can anyone suggest anything here to prevent this type of behavior that will be good for a WP install?  If there is not something like this available then I would not mind implementing my own script that logs this info into a file for me or if there is already something like this available then that is even better.  Seems this is a recurring problem with Adwords

Open to suggestions

Comment: IP != person, if  I wanted to fake click anything using hundreds of IP's i could. In short theres noting you can actully do

Comment: Thanks Dagon, you are right -- That is why the traffic source and time on site is also key